# Finding values from different rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe comprising the data and another dataframe, containing a single row carrying indices.

```
data = {'col_1': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'col_2': [3, 4, 9, 8],'col_3': [5, 5, 6, 9],'col_4': [8, 7, 6, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ind = {'ind_1': [2], 'ind_2': [1],'ind_3': [3],'ind_4': [2]}
ind = pd.DataFrame(ind)
```

Both have the same number of columns. I want to extract the values of `df` corresponding to the index stored in `ind` so that I get a single row at the end.

For this data it should be: `[6, 4, 9, 6]`. I tried `df.loc[ind.loc[0]]` but that of course gives me four different rows, not one.

The other idea I have is to `zip` columns and rows and iterate over them. But I feel there should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can go to NumPy domain and index there:

```py
In [14]: df.to_numpy()[ind, np.arange(len(df.columns))]
Out[14]: array([[6, 4, 9, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

this pairs up `2, 1, 3, 2` from `ind` and `0, 1, 2, 3` from 0 to number of columns - 1; so we get the values at `[2, 0]`, `[1, 1]` and so on.

---

There's also `df.lookup` but it's being deprecated, so...

```py
In [19]: df.lookup(ind.iloc[0], df.columns)
~\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython:1: FutureWarning: The 'lookup' method is deprecated and will beremoved in a future version.You can use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.locas a substitute.

Out[19]: array([6, 4, 9, 6], dtype=int64)
```